# Modules not found Error when installing Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried installing SQL Developer on Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy) using the following:

https://dev.to/ishakantony/how-to-install-oracle-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-20-04-3jpd

It was working fine and started loading. I made a new connection and started with a tutorial on SQLDeveloper
Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruaHsLtxld0

I disabled the features mentioned in this video from (11:25 to 14:25).
I disabled the following features:

1. Oracle Data Miner
2. Oracle - OLAP
3. Oracle - APEX Listener Administration
4. Oracle - Change Management
5. Oracle - Database Cart
6. Oracle  - Restful Services Administration
7. Oracle - Spatial
8. Oracle - UnitTest
9. Oracle - XML Schema
10. Full Database Migrations (full group)
    (I kept enabled subversion and git as DataModel depended on them)

Suddenly it stopped working.

The error message that I get while starting the application is :

`
Warning - could not install some modules: oracle.external.xsql - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.xsql.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.xsql oracle.external.balishare - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.balishare.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.balishare oracle.external.woodstox - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.woodstox.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.woodstox oracle.javatools_exports - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/modules/oracle.javatools/javatools-exports.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javatools_exports oracle.ide.navigator - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/extensions/oracle.ide.navigator.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.navigator oracle.idert - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/lib/idert.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.idert oracle.external.berkeleydb - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.berkeleydb.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.berkeleydb oracle.external.xmlparser - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.xmlparser.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.xmlparser oracle.ide_osgi - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/lib/oracle.ide.osgi.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide_osgi oracle.ide.searchbar - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/extensions/oracle.ide.searchbar.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.searchbar oracle.ide_print_api - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/lib/ide-print-api.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide_print_api oracle.external.xdb - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.xdb.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.xdb oracle.uic - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/lib/uic.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.uic oracle.java_annotations - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/lib/annotations.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.java_annotations oracle.ide.webbrowser - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/extensions/oracle.ide.webbrowser.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.webbrowser oracle.ide.indexing - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/extensions/oracle.ide.indexing.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.indexing oracle.external.objectweb_asm - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.objectweb-asm.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.objectweb_asm oracle.external.miglayout - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.miglayout.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.miglayout oracle.javaxide - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/lib/javax-ide.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javaxide oracle.external.xdk - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.xdk.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.xdk oracle.external.ldap - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.ldap.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.ldap oracle.external.jdbc - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.jdbc.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.jdbc oracle.ide.macros - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.ide.macros.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.macros oracle.icons - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.icons.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.icons oracle.ide.persistence - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/extensions/oracle.ide.persistence.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.persistence oracle.javatools_nodeps - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.javatools-nodeps.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javatools_nodeps oracle.external.jxlayer - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.jxlayer.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.jxlayer oracle.external.osdt - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.osdt.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.osdt oracle.peek - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/lib/peek.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.peek oracle.jewt_olaf2 - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.jewt-olaf2.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.jewt_olaf2 oracle.ide.ceditor - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/extensions/oracle.ide.ceditor.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.ceditor oracle.ide.vfs - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/extensions/oracle.ide.vfs.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.vfs oracle.external.nlsrtl - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.nlsrtl.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.nlsrtl org.eclipse.equinox.common - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/equinox/org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20100503.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.equinox.common oracle.ide.library - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.ide.library.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.library oracle.javatools_jndi_local - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.javatools-jndi-local.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javatools_jndi_local oracle.external.pki - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.pki.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.pki oracle.javatools - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/lib/javatools.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javatools oracle.javamodel_rt - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.javamodel-rt.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javamodel_rt oracle.ide - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/extensions/oracle.ide.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide oracle.jewt_core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.jewt-core.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.jewt_core oracle.ideimpl.peek - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/extensions/oracle.ideimpl.peek.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ideimpl.peek oracle.ide_boot - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/lib/ide-boot.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide_boot oracle.ide.file - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/ide/extensions/oracle.ide.file.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.file oracle.external.timing - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/external/oracle.external.timing.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.timing oracle.javatools_jdk - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /home/shashwat/Downloads/Programs/Oracle_SQL_Developer/sqldeveloper/jdev/lib/jdkver.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javatools_jdk
'

Please help me solve this issue.

I tried to reinstall the entire process after uninstalling jdk and removing the zip file.

However, surprisingly the same issue came up again and again...